# Boolean operation on n dimensional polyhedron

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, linear-programming, computational-geometry, combinatorial-optimization

A polyhedron in $R^n$ is defined by a set of half-planes: $P = \{x \in R^n \mid Ax - b \le 0\}$.

Given a set of polyhedra in $R^n$, $ P_1, P_2, \dotsc, P_k$, is there an algorithm/implementation that calculates the combination of all $k$ polyhedra $ P_1\cup P_2 \cup \dotsb \cup P_k$, and gives the final shape's vertices and facets (extreme points and faces)?

Or is this an ongoing research topic?

After a search online, I found most algorithms are focusing on 2D and 3D polyhedra. CGAL has implementations on boolean operations of 2D and 3D Nef Polyhedra  (https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Nef_2/index.html and  https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Nef_3/index.html).

Comment: You need to rewrite this question. At this time, it makes no sense.

Comment: For example, https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/spkg/polylib.html

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev I took a look at this library, it can calculate the union of polyhedra, but the union is just a list of all given polyhedra, not in terms of the final shape's vertices and facets.

Comment: @WlodAA Could you let me know which part is comfusing?

Comment: @RobinLee: I don't think it's "just a list". Here is a more detailed page about this library: http://icps.u-strasbg.fr/polylib/

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev It is in Chapter 10 of the documentation. "the union of two disjoint polyhedra is a domain consisting of two polyhedra", I also tried with a simple example using two polyhedra that have intersections, the resulting domain is a list of the two given polyhedra. Also, this library seems to only support integer matrix inputs, floating numbers are rounded.